# How to read boto3 StreamingBody into .parquet file?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boto3, parquet

I am reading a parquet file with a pandas dataframe inside.

```
o = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='zak-zak', Key='2020-01/2000001.parq')
o['Body'].read()
```

`'b\'PAR1\\x15\\x00\\x15,\\x15,,\\x15\\x02\\x15\\x00\\x15\\x06\\x15\\x08\\x00\\x00\\x02\\x00\\`
but it is in the bit-format.

How can I convert it to the normal df or file-format?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `o['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')`?

Comment: I get UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 132: invalid continuation byte